# Is git pre-installed on macOS Sierra?

Tags: terminal, macos, git

I am very new to macOS, knowing Ubuntu a little bit, and am wondering whether git is pre-installed on macOS or not. Typing

```
which -a git
```

results in

```
git is /usr/bin/git
```

But when I init a *test-repo* and checkout a *myBranch*, the command

```
git branch
```

results in a empty line. So is there anything I do forget? I installed *Homebrew* before checking for git, so maybe this causes some interdependencies?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

macOS does come with a binary at `/usr/bin/git`, however by default it's a wrapper around the command line tools installer. Running the command will print the following and return immediately.

```
note: install requested for command line developer tools
```

A prompt will ask the user to install the command line tools, with a button that downloads and installs the toolset.

[image]

Once installed, `/usr/bin/git` will be a proper version of Git compiled by Apple (noted by the ‘Apple Git’).

```
$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
```

If Git is installed using Homebrew, it will be at `/usr/local/bin/git` by default on Intel, at `/opt/homebrew/bin/git` on ARM.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Do you have any suggestions which git to use? I tried to add the current git-branch to my terminal prompt like described [here](https://gist.github.com/joseluisq/1e96c54fa4e1e5647940), but this resulted in some errors, where always _$(parse_git_bash)_ was written behind the standard prompt.

Comment: @marco05772 The homebrew git is a slightly newer version 2.31.1 versus 2.24.3. So use the one you're most comfortable with.