# Is there a list of pre-installed command-line tools for macOS?

Tags: terminal, command-line, install, xcode

I'm currently in the process of developing some shell scripts but have run into a problem: whilst I am able to execute numerous commands on my Mac, when I try to run it on other people's computers I get `Command not found` errors indicating that they do not have the specific command line tools installed.

It is my belief that many of these tools come as a result of installing Xcode and other package managers like Homebrew. My question is: is there a list or another way of finding out if a specific command (tool) is pre-installed on a standard Mac computer (without Xcode installed) without having to manually test it on someone else's computer?

For example, [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304100/is-git-pre-installed-on-macos-sierra) post hints that `git` is pre-installed which is only the case if you have installed Xcode, otherwise, `git` is unavailable.

P.S. For my specific case, I am wondering if `hexdump` is pre-installed or not (without Xcode)

Comment: and this is not it ? https://ss64.com/osx/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it looks like there is a simple way to know that.

At Terminal prompt hit the Escape (or TAB) **twice**

It will ask you if you want to `Display all 1527 possibilities`? (y or n).

Or here https://ss64.com/osx/

Comment: Not "escape", but "tab"

Comment: Unfortunately, that also displays commands like `nmap` and `atom`, both of which were installed retrospectively. Therefore, I think the link you posted (https://ss64.com/osx/) is more relevant as it looks to only include pre-installed tools. Thank you!

Comment: @mbamac it looks like both work

Comment: worked for me but I had 3020 commands. Wonder why such a big difference.

Comment: @jmh it depends what apps you have installed